# position fixed not working in IE9 contents loaded in div via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, css

This is working fine in FF,Opera, Chrome. Problem is in IE only.
I have a div in which I am loading below contents

```
  <a href="javascript:;" onClick="$('.test').show();">Add</a>

  <div class="test" style="position:fixed;width: 300px;height:200px;display:none;">
     hello friends
  </div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
asadsadsad<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>jsjdhahdgasdhg<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>kshdksjdh
```

When I click on anchor tag, box shows up (display none to block) but the div doesn't get fixed position it moves with scrollbars :(

To make position fixed work in IE I am using

Is this happening because contents are loaded via ajax? What could be the solution?

Comment: you have a typo correct style -- > ";width: 300px;height:200px;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/>` into your `<head>`.

Comment: Your solution worked :) u Know i have spend 4-5 hours solving this....my code is huge, i removed everything and left only 4 lines but stil it wasnt working....that realy made me crazy, U saved me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the test div to `position:absolute` and also, you misspelled the height attribute:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="$('.test').show();">Add</a>

<div class="test" style="position:absolute;width:300px;height:200px;display:none;">
   hello friends
</div>

<br/>123<br/>123<br/>123
```

Comment: As far as I can understand, the OP wants to use `position:fixed`.

Comment: @Teemu He wants it to stay in the same spot, and not move with the page and scrollbars. Which is absolute, not fixed. I believe he's just using the wrong word trying to describe it.

Comment: Nope. With `position:absolute` positioned elements are moving when scrolling, when positioned as `fixed` they are not.